# Conditional formatting based on frequency

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a range (A1:L200) that has only numerical values (0-37).
I have a formula that shows the frequency that each value appears:
=FREQUENCY(A1:L200, N1:N38)

How can I use this formula or something similar with conditional formatting to depict a heat map over the range where the most frequent values are some color and lesser frequencies are varying lighter shades?

Answer (score 1):

Heat maps can be created with the **Color scale** option in [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413), but that requires that the cells being formatted contain the values that determine the color.

One way to create a frequency heat map is to calculate the frequencies, map each value to its frequency, and put the *frequencies* in a table *formatted* so that the cell *displays* the value along with its frequency. This way, the cell contains the frequency but displays the value. The color scale format will only see the frequency and thus shows a frequency heat map as specified in the question.

To implement that, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  data, Sheet1!A1:L200, 
  values, sequence(38, 1, 0), 
  freqs, frequency(data, values), 
  table, hstack(values, freqs), 
  map(data, lambda(v, 
    query( 
      vlookup(v, table, 2, false), 
      "format Col1 '""" & v & """ ""(""0"")""' ", 
      0 
    ) 
  )) 
)
```

When the value 37 has a frequency of 1, the relevant cell in the new sheet will display `37 (1)` and will have a value of `1`. Format the new sheet as **Format > Conditional formatting > Color scale**.

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985),
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
[hstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190756),
[query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343)
and
[vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318).

Comment: Using formatting to 'hide' the numerical value in this way is absolute genius.

Comment: Thanks. The `format` clause has always been in the query language, but it only became available in Google Sheets a year or two back. It's a great help.